# Using call_user_func() with objects

Tags: php, symfony1

The following two statements should be identical, yet the commented out statement does not work. Can anyone explain ?

```
$peer = GeneralToolkit::getPeerModel($model);
//return call_user_func(get_class($peer).'::retrieveByPK',array($comment->getItemId()));
return $peer->retrieveByPK($comment->getItemId());
```

PS: I am using PHP 5.2.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two calls are not the same. You are calling:

```
return GeneralToolkit::retrieveByPK(array($comment->getItemId());
```

So of course you get a different answer. This is the correct code:

```
return call_user_func(array($peer, 'retrieveByPK'), $comment->getItemId());
```

Unless 'retrieveByPK' is static, but in that case you should use one of these calls (these all do the same thing):

```
return call_user_func(
    get_class($peer) . '::retrieveByPK', 
    $comment->getItemId());

return call_user_func(
    array(get_class($peer), 'retrieveByPK'), 
    $comment->getItemId());

return call_user_func_array(
    get_class($peer) . '::retrieveByPK', 
    array($comment->getItemId()));

return call_user_func_array(
    array(get_class($peer), 'retrieveByPK'), 
    array($comment->getItemId()));
```

So in that case your error was in using `array()` while calling `call_user_func()` instead of `call_user_func_array()`.

**Explanation:**

Classes have two main types of functions: static and non-static. In normal code, static functions are called using `ClassName::functionName()`. For non-static functions you need first to create an object using `$objectInstance = new ClassName()`, then call the function using `$objectInstance->functionName()`.

When using callbacks you also make a distinction between static and non-static functions. Static functions are stored as either a string `"ClassName::functionName"` or an array containing two strings `array("ClassName", "FunctionName")`.

A callback on a non-static function is always an array containing the object to call and the function name as a string: `array($objectInstance, "functionName)`.

See the [PHP Callback documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) for more details.

Comment: Your code is correct (I tried it). I still dont understand however, how my commented out line is equivalent to the line you wrote. I thought get_class($peer) would return the name of the peer class, as a string, which would then be appended to the '::retrieveByPK' string, to complete the method name. Please explain why get_class($peer) returns 'GeneralToolkit' - or did you make a mistake?

Comment: As it turns out, this also works: return call_user_func(array(get_class($peer), 'retrieveByPK'), $comment->getItemId());

Comment: From your example we cannot be sure that get_class($peer) does return GeneralToolkit, but if you have symfony experience i guess it's possible to know that. If it's true, which is something i don't know.

Answer (score 3):

```
return call_user_func(
    array($peer,'retrieveByPK'),
    $comment->getItemId()
);
```

is the equivalent of

```
return $peer->retrieveByPK($comment->getItemId());
```

The first argument gives an object reference, and a function name. The second argument gives the arguments passed to the function that is being called.

The `::` syntax is used to reference static methods and properties of a *class*. Which is different from referencing non-static methods and properties.

Comment: It is wrong. retrieveByPk is not a static function in the working example.

Comment: Matjis is right, your code did not work, and the second solution you offered does not unfortunately, answer my original question.

Comment: Right, i misunderstood the question a bit. Updated my answer to reflect this.